# Is it possible to do append blob restore using multiple threads?

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage

**Which version of the SDK was used?**

v0.11.0

**Which platform are you using? (ex: Windows, Linux, Debian)**

Windows

**What problem was encountered?**

[Approach]

1. Acquire lease before goroutine started
2. Calling **AppendBlock(ctx, bytes.NewReader(rangeData), azblob.AppendBlobAccessConditions{}, nil)**
   concurrently inside go routine.
3. We are using **"azblob.AppendPositionAccessConditions{IfAppendPositionEqual: subRangeSize}}"** in
   AppendBlock call.

It is working well without threads but fails when using goroutine
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=AppendPositionConditionNotMet) =====
Description=The append position condition specified was not met.

```
FourMegaByteAsBytes := common.FourMegaByteAsBytes
var strLeaseID string = ""
var respAcquireLease *azblob.BlobAcquireLeaseResponse
subRangeSize := int64(0)

//Restore data to Append Blob
for currpos := int64(0); currpos < SourceBlobLength; {

            
    subRangeSize = int64(math.Min(float64(SourceBlobLength-currpos), float64(FourMegaByteAsBytes)))
    rangeData := make([]byte, subRangeSize)

        
    if len(strLeaseID) == 0 {
        //Acquire the Lease for Restore Blob
        respAcquireLease, err = blobURL.AcquireLease(ctx, "", -1, azblob.ModifiedAccessConditions{})
        if err != nil {
            _, err = blobURL.AppendBlock(ctx, bytes.NewReader(rangeData),
                azblob.AppendBlobAccessConditions{}, nil)
        } else {
            strLeaseID = respAcquireLease.LeaseID()
            _, err1 := blobURL.AppendBlock(ctx, bytes.NewReader(rangeData),
                azblob.AppendBlobAccessConditions{
                    azblob.ModifiedAccessConditions{},
                    azblob.LeaseAccessConditions{LeaseID: strLeaseID},
                    azblob.AppendPositionAccessConditions{},
                }, nil)
            if err1 != nil {
                log.Fatal(err1)
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        _, err = blobURL.AppendBlock(ctx, bytes.NewReader(rangeData),
            azblob.AppendBlobAccessConditions{
                azblob.ModifiedAccessConditions{},
                azblob.LeaseAccessConditions{LeaseID: strLeaseID},
                azblob.AppendPositionAccessConditions{}}, nil)
    }
        
    currpos += subRangeSize
}
```

**Have you found a mitigation/solution?**
No

Answer (score 0):

Appending to a blob requires that you have a lease. Therefore, only the client (aka thread) that has the lease can write to the blob.

So the answer to your question is No, it is not possible to do it at the same time.

There are 2 possible work arounds:

1. If all your threads write to a queue. Then a single process reads from the queue an writes to the blob.
2. Program such that the tread waits for the lease to be available. Note the minimum duration of a lease is 15 seconds.